# Area 51: designate a place where you can suggest questions for proposals

Tags: feature-request, area-51

I would like to ask for a proposal about [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa904594), but I don't have the knowledge to do so, and I don't want to create a proposal where I'm the one asking.

I looked and didn't find where I could "ask for proposals when you think that is a good idea, but you are a newbie at it", and there is nothing in [FAQ](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) or in the **Advanced Super Ninja Search Options**

I think that it is a good idea create a place where you can suggest questions for proposals. When you don't have the expertise about the subject, but still think that it is a great idea.

Comment: Are there questions about [LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linq) that would not be on topic on SO?  I've linked to the tag, which has over 10,000 questions.

Comment: @justkt, consider expanding that and posting it as an answer. (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Area 51 has a [Discussion Zone](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/) where you can post ideas, but I think that what you're describing sounds like it belongs on a normal proposal.  New site proposals need examples of good off-topic questions as well as on-topic questions in order to be well defined.

Comment: i'm taking you as answer, because is what i asked i took a look at the faq before post it, and I had not understood, where it talks about what can, and can not be posted.

Answer (score 4):

Are there questions about LINQ that would not be on topic on SO?  The [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linq) has over 10,000 questions.  I am no LINQ expert, but I think there would need to be a significant area of LINQ that wasn't programming-related for a proposal to be allowed, much less for one to thrive.

In other words, it has to have a set of questions similar to those in the about-to-be-launched [SharePoint Overflow](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/28921/sharepoint-overflow?referrer=6QiN4B2VHGMnXLaDPCj7kA2) that don't belong on SO.

In general, though, if you want a proposal with expert-level questions on an issue, how about *asking some experts* to help you get it off the ground.  Find their websites, blogs, user accounts on forums, etc. and contact them.  Then any one of you can set it up, confident in a small core.

Comment: Now i understood what you mean. Thanks for the explanation anyway. i took the other answer cuz answer what is asked in the title. Too bad that i can't vote UP to you (low rep here =X)